# Windows Installer XML(WIX) Help: Not able to execute shell command through exeCommand

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Following is my code. I need to install the .inf and .cer files after execution of the MSI file. I have tried referring to various wix resources but couldn't find anything. I am testing the installer on a virtual machine but it doesn't seem to work. I am new to wix and need help regarding this by going through the code and pointing out my mistakes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Cal" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Cal" UpgradeCode="my-code">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />




    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />


    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Cal" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />

    </Feature>
    <!--<CustomActionRef Id="InstallAction1" />-->
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Cal" />
        <Directory Id="SilInst" Name="BackInst">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

      <Component Id="P2">
        <File Source="C1.sys" />
      </Component>


      <Component Id="P6">
        <File Source="C1.inf" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="P7">
        <File Source="C1.cer" />
      </Component>

    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id='InstallAction1' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' ExeCommand='RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 C1.inf' Execute='deferred'
                      Return='check'/>
    <CustomAction Id='InstallAction2' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' ExeCommand='certutil -addstore C1.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher' Execute='deferred'
                     Return='check'/>


    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="InstallAction2" After='InstallFiles'/>
     <Custom Action="InstallAction1" After='InstallAction2'/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Open your MSI in Orca or Insteadit and check in the InstallExecuteSequence table if your Custom action is there.

Comment: For drivers installations you should consider using the Difxapp extension: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/difxapp/driver.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot, create an installation log, then search for the custom action id.
Installing driver and certificate on machine typically requires elevated permissions. Therefore use `Impersonate="no"` for your custom actions. See [How to run a Custom Action inside an MSI created in WiX with elevated privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476779/how-to-run-a-custom-action-inside-an-msi-created-in-wix-with-elevated-privileges)